# How to setup subversion authentication with bitnami Trac stack

Tags: windows, svn, trac, bitnami

I have installed the native Bitnami Track Stack on a windows server and I have it working with tortoiseSVN.

Currently all users are anonymous and can checkout & commit.

I have read the bitnami website on setting up svn authentication (svnserve.conf), but this appears to be ignored, even after I have restarted the tracApache & tracSubversion services.

Can anyone point out what I'm missing?

Paresh

Answer (score 1):

Solved
Found this page http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindows/Advanced.

Trac and Subversion now both authenticate with user accounts setup on the server.

The file to edit is in `[bitnami install dir]\apache2\conf\httpd.conf`